# Create Delegate-Event Model Sample Program in Java using callback

Tags: java, events, callback

I am a greenhorn in java . I want to learn more about how java event handling works. So I need a simple example demonstrating custom callback in java. It should be something like 2 or more class can register  in callback system. When some event occurs [A timer tick during every 20 seconds] registered classes must receive a notification. I have found a lot of examples explaining java callback but I am searching for a simple example. Somebody could please help me?
Lots of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an ultra-simple example of callbacks at work:

```
public class Timer {
  private final List<Runnable> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();

  public void onTick(Runnable r) { synchronized (callbacks) { callbacks.add(r); } }

  public void start() {
    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        while (true) {
          synchronized (callbacks) {
            callbacks.forEach(Runnable::run);
          }
          Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(3));
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }).start();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Timer t = new Timer();
    t.onTick(() -> System.out.println("Ide vrijeme, prođe rok"));
    t.onTick(() -> System.out.println("Eto vraga skok na skok"));
    t.start();
  }
}
```

I hope it is simple enough to be self-explanatory.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand.Can you please do it with separate methods for registration , timer tick etc.

Comment: `onTick()` is the method for registration and ticks happen within the `while (true)` loop.

Comment: If it's not obvious, I am reusing the `Runnable` interface as the callback.